# How can I read a string from a file, convert it to int, store the value in memory and then access the value and print it on screen?

Tags: python, sensors, temperature

I need to read a temperature reading from a DS18B20 sensor using Raspberry Pi 3 and Python.
The problem is the refresh rate of the sensor (~1 sec)
I need to read from `sys/bus/w1/devices/28-041670f43bff/w1_slave` and use the integer i get to display a temperature on a 7 segment display connected directly to my GPIOs (not using any hardware multiplexing - i2c....etc)

In order to display a two digit temperature, I need to turn on and off the digits really fast (faster than the sensor refreshes)

This is the small piece of code used to get the integer temperature:

```
def temperature():
    with open ("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-041670f43bff/w1_slave") as q:
        r=q.read()
        temp=r[69:71]
        t=int (temp)
        return t
```

But i need to call this function many times per second in order to get a good display on the 7 segment display.

This is how i thought of doing it:

```
#the temperature() function returns a two digit int
while True:
    GPIO.output(31,0)
    GPIO.output(temp[temperature()/10], 1)  # temp is a dictionary used to know which segments to light up to show numbers
    time.sleep(0.0005)
    GPIO.output(31,1)
    GPIO.output(37,0)
    GPIO.output(temp[temperature()%10], 1)
    time.sleep(0.0005)
    GPIO.output(37,1)
```

But this code just makes one digit light up, wait ~1sec, light up the other digit, wait ~1sec.....and so on.

Any ideas of how to do this are very appreciated.

Comment: Is this question about reading the temperature, or running the GPIO?

Comment: about reading the temperature FAST in order to run the GPIO.

Comment: I doubt reading it is all that slow.  Have you timed it?  If it is slow you could keep the file open and seek(0) before each read, but I would be surprised if that were much faster.  Did I ask if you had timed it?

Comment: if I run this code:`with open ("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-041670f43bff/w1_slave") as q:
        r=q.read()
        temp=r[69:71]
        t=int (temp)
        print t`

Comment: if i run the above code in a while loop it will print  23(the temperature now) every second.        23, wait 1 sec, 23, nothing for 1 second, 23.....

Comment: Well this is after all a temperature.  It will not likely change very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd throw the display routine into its own thread so that you don't have to think about it in your main loop.  The code below should demonstrate this concept.  Set "testing" to False to see if it works with your hardware.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import threading
import Queue
import random

# Set this to False to read the temperature from a real sensor and display it on a 7-digit display.
testing = True

def temperature_read(q):
    # Read the temperature at one second intervals.
    while True:
        if testing:
            r = '-' * 69 + '%02d' % (random.randrange(100)) + 'blahblah' * 4
        else:
            r = open('/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-041670f43bff/w1_slave', 'r').read()

        print r

        # The temperature is represented as two digits in a long string.
        # Push the digits into the queue as a tuple of integers (one per digit).
        q.put((int(r[69]), int(r[70])))

        # Wait for next reading.
        # (Will w1_slave block until the next reading?  If so, this could be eliminated.)
        time.sleep(1.0)

def temperature_display(q):
    # Display the temperature.

    # Temperature is two digits, stored separately (high/low) for more efficient handling.
    temperature_h = temperature_l = 0


    while True:
        # Is there a new temperature reading waiting for us?
        if not q.empty():
            temperature = q.get()

            # If it's None, we're done.
            if temperature is None:
                break   

            # Load the two digits (high and low) representing the temperature.
            (temperature_h, temperature_l) = temperature

        if testing:
            print 'displayH', temperature_h
            time.sleep(0.05)
            print 'displayL', temperature_l
            time.sleep(0.05)

        else:
            GPIO.output(31,0)
            GPIO.output(temperature_h, 1)  # temp is a dictionary used to know which segments to light up to show numbers
            time.sleep(0.0005)
            GPIO.output(31,1)
            GPIO.output(37,0)
            GPIO.output(temperature_l, 1)
            time.sleep(0.0005)
            GPIO.output(37,1)

    # Clean up here.  Turn off all pins?   




# Make a queue to communicate with the display thread.
temperature_queue = Queue.Queue()

# Run the display in a separate thread.
temperature_display_thread = threading.Thread(target=temperature_display, args=(temperature_queue,))
temperature_display_thread.start()

# Run the reader.
try:
        temperature_read(temperature_queue)
except:
        # An uncaught exception happened.  (It could be a keyboard interrupt.)
        None

# Tell the display thread to stop.
temperature_queue.put(None)

# Wait for the thread to end.
temperature_display_thread.join()
```

To support another reading (transmission), I just put it in the read loop rather than adding another thread for it.  I changed the queue so that you could easily move it to another thread but I suspect you'll add more inputs so this is probably a reasonable way to do it unless the read frequency of one needs to be much different.  (Even then, you could do things with counters in the loop.)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import threading
import Queue
import random

# Set this to False to read the temperature from a real sensor and display it on a 7-digit display.
testing = True

def observe(q):
    while True:

        # Make a temperature reading.
        if testing:
            r = '-' * 69 + '%02d' % (random.randrange(100)) + 'blahblah' * 4
        else:
            r = open('/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-041670f43bff/w1_slave', 'r').read()

        print 'temperature ->', r

        # The temperature is represented as two digits in a long string.
        # Push the digits into the queue as a tuple of integers (one per digit).
        q.put(('temperature', int(r[69]), int(r[70])))

        # Make a transmission reading.
        if testing:
            r = random.randrange(1,6)
        else:
            r = 0   # Put your transmission reading code here.

        print 'transmission ->', r

        q.put(('transmission', r))

        # Wait for next reading.
        # (Will w1_slave block until the next reading?  If so, this could be eliminated.)
        time.sleep(1.0)


def display(q):
    # Display the temperature.

    # Temperature is two digits, stored separately (high/low) for more efficient handling.
    temperature_h = temperature_l = transmission = 0


    while True:
        # Is there a new temperature reading waiting for us?
        if not q.empty():
            reading = q.get()

            # If it's None, we're done.
            if reading is None:
                break   
            elif reading[0] == 'temperature':
                # Load the two digits (high and low) representing the temperature.
                (x, temperature_h, temperature_l) = reading
            elif reading[0] == 'transmission':
                (x, transmission) = reading

        if testing:
            print 'displayH', temperature_h
            time.sleep(0.05)
            print 'displayL', temperature_l
            time.sleep(0.05)
            print 'transmission', transmission
            time.sleep(0.05)

        else:
            GPIO.output(31,0)
            GPIO.output(temperature_h, 1)  # temp is a dictionary used to know which segments to light up to show numbers
            time.sleep(0.0005)
            GPIO.output(31,1)
            GPIO.output(37,0)
            GPIO.output(temperature_l, 1)
            time.sleep(0.0005)
            GPIO.output(37,1)

    # Clean up here.  Turn off all pins?

# Make a queue to communicate with the display thread.
readings_queue = Queue.Queue()

# Run the display in a separate thread.
display_thread = threading.Thread(target=display, args=(readings_queue,))
display_thread.start()

# Observe the inputs.
try:
    observe(readings_queue)
except:
    # An uncaught exception happened.  (It could be a keyboard interrupt.)
    None

# Tell the display thread to stop.
readings_queue.put(None)

# Wait for the thread to end.
display_thread.join()
```

Here's a version which only reads the temperature every tenth time but reads the transmission every time.  I think you'll see how to easily tweak this to meet your needs.

I would make separate threads for each reader but it would complicate the thread management quite a bit.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import threading
import Queue
import random

# Set this to False to read the temperature from a real sensor and display it on a 7-digit display.
testing = True

def observe(q):
    count = 0

    while True:
        # Only read the temperature every tenth time.
        if (count % 10 == 0):
            # Make a temperature reading.
            if testing:
                r = '-' * 69 + '%02d' % (random.randrange(100)) + 'blahblah' * 4
            else:
                r = open('/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-041670f43bff/w1_slave', 'r').read()

            print 'temperature ->', r

            # The temperature is represented as two digits in a long string.
            # Push the digits into the queue as a tuple of integers (one per digit).
            q.put(('temperature', int(r[69]), int(r[70])))

        # Make a transmission reading.
        if testing:
            r = random.randrange(1,6)
        else:
            r = 0   # Put your transmission reading code here.

        print 'transmission ->', r

        q.put(('transmission', r))

        # Wait for next reading.
        if testing:
            time.sleep(0.5)
        else:
            time.sleep(0.1)

        count += 1

def display(q):
    # Display the temperature.

    # Temperature is two digits, stored separately (high/low) for more efficient handling.
    temperature_h = temperature_l = transmission = 0


    while True:
        # Is there a new temperature reading waiting for us?
        if not q.empty():
            reading = q.get()

            # If it's None, we're done.
            if reading is None:
                break   
            elif reading[0] == 'temperature':
                # Load the two digits (high and low) representing the temperature.
                (x, temperature_h, temperature_l) = reading
            elif reading[0] == 'transmission':
                (x, transmission) = reading

        if testing:
            print 'displayH', temperature_h
            time.sleep(0.05)
            print 'displayL', temperature_l
            time.sleep(0.05)
            print 'transmission', transmission
            time.sleep(0.05)

        else:
            GPIO.output(31,0)
            GPIO.output(temperature_h, 1)  # temp is a dictionary used to know which segments to light up to show numbers
            time.sleep(0.0005)
            GPIO.output(31,1)
            GPIO.output(37,0)
            GPIO.output(temperature_l, 1)
            time.sleep(0.0005)
            GPIO.output(37,1)

    # Clean up here.  Turn off all pins?

# Make a queue to communicate with the display thread.
readings_queue = Queue.Queue()

# Run the display in a separate thread.
display_thread = threading.Thread(target=display, args=(readings_queue,))
display_thread.start()

# Observe the inputs.
try:
    observe(readings_queue)
except:
    # An uncaught exception happened.  (It could be a keyboard interrupt.)
    None

# Tell the display thread to stop.
readings_queue.put(None)

# Wait for the thread to end.
display_thread.join()
```

Comment: Yes. This does exactly what I need. The temperature updates and is displayed correctly. THANK YOU

Comment: Could you show me how to add another thread to this? I have another piece of code that acts like a gear (kart shifting gears) indicator (1...2...3...4...5...4..3..etc) that I want to run at the same time with this and on the same 4 digit 7 segment display .   THANK YOU again.

Comment: I'm new here so I'm not sure if I'm doing this right...

I added code for the transmission onto my answer.  Does that work?

Comment: Yes. I saw the code. Will try it tomorrow, since today I am very busy. But it should work just fine. Inforgot to mention that i increment the values of the numbers shown on the display by pressing 2 buttons. One for going + and one for going -.

Comment: `i=0
x=0
while(True):
    GPIO.output(36,1)
    GPIO.output(36,0)
    
    while (GPIO.input(11)==0 and i<1):
        GPIO.output(18,1)

    if (GPIO.input(11)==1):
        i+=1
        x+=10
        if i==7:
            i=6
            x=60
        else:
            GPIO.output(gears[i],1)
            GPIO.output(gears[x],0)
            time.sleep(.2)

    if (GPIO.input(13)==1):
        i-=1
        x-=10
        if i==0:
            i=1
            x=10
        GPIO.output(gears[i],1)
        GPIO.output(gears[x],0)
        time.sleep(.2)`

Comment: This is the transmission code. Will it work in the code you gave me? Remember that this has to update every time I hit a button. So I know what gear I am in.

Comment: I have managed to make the code put another value in the queue as 'transmission', but the problem is that it reads the queue only once every 1 second (or am i getting ti wrong?) so if i change gears more than 1 every second the display is not correct

Answer (score 2):

Rather than implement this functionality on your own, you should instead use the libraries out there that address this particular bit of your code inherently. In this case, I'd suggest you use W1ThermSensor. You can find the documentation at:

> https://github.com/timofurrer/w1thermsensor

and you can install it using:

```
pip install w1thermsensor
```

It does support the DS18B20, and offers an exact analogue to your use case in the README.

From the docs for the package:

```
from w1thermsensor import W1ThermSensor

sensor = W1ThermSensor()
temperature_in_celsius = sensor.get_temperature()
temperature_in_fahrenheit = sensor.get_temperature(W1ThermSensor.DEGREES_F)
temperature_in_all_units = sensor.get_temperatures([
    W1ThermSensor.DEGREES_C,
    W1ThermSensor.DEGREES_F,
    W1ThermSensor.KELVIN
])
```

In many cases, particularly for popular hardware devices, you'll find that there are libraries already available to use within python, and that will all you to quickly move on to writing the bits of code unique to your own particular needs.

> Note: According to the technical discussion in the following link, if the DS18B20 is set to 12-bit temperature resolution, the temperature conversion will take 750 ms, or 3/4 of a second. If you set the hardware to do 9-bit resolution, the conversion time in hardware is 93.75 ms. I suspect this is the root of your once-per-second issue.
>
> https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4377
>
> There is some discussion of this issue in this Question:
>
> https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14278/how-to-change-ds18b20-reading-resolution
>
> See the second Answer, regarding the configDS18B20 utility.
>
> With the resolution set to 9-bit, you *may* be able to adjust the `w1thermsensor` `RETRY_DELAY_SECONDS` / `RETRY_ATTEMPTS` value combination in the source code and get what you need. It's unclear to me if the retry delay has any affect on the actual polling of the device. It looks like it is there for device finding. Though, as I said, that interval *may* impact polling a single device. I simply didn't read through the source code enough to see when and where it comes into play.

---

Happy New Year!

Comment: Thank you very much for this idea. I will use the package. But this function still only shows temperature once about every second or so.

Comment: @PinteaMihaita See my updated answer. You _might_ be able to fix this by changing the temperature resolution on the hardware itself, but it doesn't look like you're going to get much better than 1 second updates by doing anything in your software _without_ changing the config on the hardware. Even then, it's unclear whether that'll help, as per the Answer from raspberrypi.stackexchange.com that I mentioned above. It's your best shot, though. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Will try to do that also. Maybe I can gat even better speed. THANKS

Comment: You're welcome. I had fun researching the problem. It that approach works, come back and add an update to your answer letting us know if it solved it. I'm really curious about this one.

Comment: Newer versions of the w1thermsensor package support `W1ThermSensor.set_precision(precision, persistent=False)` to set the sensor precision